WSO2 ESB: Using iterate and aggregate mediators without sending the split messages to an endpoint
In my scenario, there are no backend calls. I need to update some details of records in a database by looping through each record and sending a single aggregated email notification to the user with the details of the updated records. Additionally, if any failures occur during the update process, the email notification should include both the successfully updated records and the failed records.
I tried to achieve this using a combination of Iterate and Aggregate mediators. However, since my process does not include any Send or Call mediators, the iterate loop does not terminate.
I also tried to use the ForEach and Enrich mediators. I looped through the records using the ForEach mediator and appended each record's email payload to the body using the Enrich mediator. While this works fine in the success scenario, in the failure scenario, I cannot retrieve the aggregated payload in the OnError, because once we exit from the ForEach loop only, it automatically aggregates the split segments.
Also, I tried using  as mentioned in this Stack Overflow question: WSO2 ESB, Using Aggregate mediator without send/call in iterate mediator, but this did not work for me either.

You can achieve this requirement by isolating the aggregate mediator to a separate sequence and calling it inside the iterate mediator and inside the onError sequence. Refer the following sequences and update your logic accordingly.

Sequence containing the Iterate Mediator

<sequence name="iterateSeq" onError="errorSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <iterate expression="somthing" id="iterator" sequential="true">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <!-- Integration logic to be executed on each item -->
                <sequence key="aggregateSeq"/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <drop/>
</sequence>


Sequence containing the Aggregate Mediator

<sequence name="aggregateSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <aggregate id="iterator">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="something">
            <!-- On completion logic here -->
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
  <drop/>
</sequence>


onError sequence used in the iterate sequence

<sequence name="errorSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- Error handling logic here -->
    <!-- Call the aggregateSeq to aggregate the error -->
    <sequence key="aggregateSeq">
</sequence>


Currently I'm using the same approach, but my iterate loop is not terminating because I'm not using any send or call mediators.

I tested the above workaround without call mediators and it works without any issue. What do you mean by "iterate loop is not terminating" ?
















The flow doesn't continue after the iterate mediator
I used loopback mediator(https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/loopback-Mediator/) to achieve this and it worked for me.
<proxy name="Proxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <iterate expression="//*[local-name()='record']" sequential="true" id="iterate">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <sequence key="Iterate_SEQ"/>
                        <sequence key="Aggregate_SEQ"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <loopback/>    
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
           <respond/> 
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>


<sequence name="Aggregate_SEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <aggregate id="iterate">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="somthing">
            <!-- on complete logic -->
            <sequence key="Email_SEQ"/>
            <loopback/>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
</sequence>

<sequence name="Iterate_SEQ" onError="Fault_SEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- Iterate logic -->
</sequence>

<sequence name="Fault_SEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- fault logic -->
    <sequence key="Aggregate_SEQ"/>
</sequence>

